# Warp.js date starting from previous date

Tags: javascript

This script using warp.js works great starting from the current date. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work starting from a previous date like Jan 2nd, 1986?

warp.js
https://github.com/mattbradley/warpjs/blob/master/README.md

Thanks!

```
    <body>
        <script src="warp.js"></script>


        <div id="container"></div>
        <span id="info"></span><br>
        <span id="time"></span>
        <span id="time2"></span>

        <script>


        setInterval(function() {

          //specify a start date here like Jan 2 1986

          Date.warp.speed(3);
          var now = new Date;
          //new date put out the warped start date above?

          var dateD = [now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate(), now.getFullYear()];
          var dateE = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()];
          var MDY = dateD.join("/");
          var HMS = dateE.join(":");
          time.innerHTML = (MDY);
          time2.innerHTML = (HMS);

        }, 1000);
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Mind sharing what the current output is along with the output you are expecting?

Comment: Warp speed just makes the current clock tick at whatever factor is in the (). So if 1, it is 1 second per second. If 2, it is 2 seconds per second. The issue is, if I specify a different date to start from, it jumps to the current date and warps the current date instead of a previous date I have specified. Is there a way to preserve the date I specify and warp from there?

Comment: In this example, you have not specified any date. Please update your post and add the code that is generating error or issue.

Comment: Actually I did. Not only does this var now = new Date; generate a current date, I would like to have it start from Jan 2nd, 1986 as I stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. You have to use the clock() function so set your custom date, and it will then warp from that custom date.

```
Date.warp.clock(customDate);
```